# How to receive contact name via Twilio WhatsApp

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

I am using the [Twilio API for WhatsApp](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api) in a sandbox, for prototyping and testing. According to the Facebook / WhatsApp documentation, there are several types of [inbound notifications](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/webhooks/inbound) that may be delivered to your unique Webhook.

Twilio API documentation is very limited and doesn’t mention any of the more advanced scenarios. For example retrieving the customers name, [which should be present in every webhook request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/api/webhooks/inbound)…

When I inspect the webhook, the body payload is very limited. Is there any way to receive the original channelData?

Comment: no not until you get approved from facebook

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya, what do you mean? The Twilio WhatsApp Sandbox is a verified Business Account.

Comment: but the API data are limited, the same number with different token is distributed with all the twilio users

Comment: I still don’t see the problem. Guess this is just lacking in their implemenation, so I wonder if someone from Twilio has a work-around. You don’t have to do a request to receive the name of the person who is initiating the chat, it should be included by default.

Comment: I have been working with twilio and whatsapp so long, you wont get user's information while having sandbox rather then the number

Comment: Thanks, @NikhilSavaliya. Since I am working on a package for other people using Twilio WhatsApp, do you know in which field it will be outside of the Sandbox environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this feature is not implemented yet. I received the following statement from Twilio.

> Unfortunately we don't support the Contact name being included in the inbound Whatsapp message posted to your webhook at this time. I've raised a feature request for this with the Product Team in hopes that we'll have this feature available in the near future.

Comment: Any way to track the feature request?

Comment: No, Twilio is not open about their roadmap / feature requests. You need to contact their support.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the sender's name using the 'ProfileName' key from the request form.

Comment: what do you mean by "request form" I don't see it in the webhook request body or if I fetch the whole message by the message sid via the messaging api.

Comment: I finally found a [reference](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/webhook-request#whatsapp-specific-parameters) for this but I'm not seeing it come through with the sandbox number